# change author block in iccv template

Tags: titles, templates

I am trying to modify this template:
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/iccv-2017---international-conference-on-computer-vision

I want the email below the respective author name and a common institution even further below. I got some errors.

I changed the lines 30-44 into this:

```
\author{First Author\\
{\tt\small firstauthor@i1.org}
% For a paper whose authors are all at the same institution,
% omit the following lines up until the closing ``}''.
% Additional authors and addresses can be added with ``\and'',
% just like the second author.
% To save space, use either the email address or home page, not both
\and
Second Author\\
{\tt\small secondauthor@i2.org}
}

%HERE I need the university name
```

I cannot make it work no matter what, haha this is so annoying!

Comment: I bet the editors of the conference will just revert your changes. Have you checked with them?

Comment: @Johannes_B it's not for the conference hehe!

Comment: Are allowed to use it for other purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have well understood your question, but i have managed to show the address : 
[image]

just by removing `\def\iccvPaperID{****} % *** Enter the ICCV Paper ID here`, on line 19.

Answer (score 1):

I found it helpful to change line 8 to the following,

`\usepackage[cvprfinal]{cvpr}` from `\usepackage[review]{cvpr}`